# Excel - AverageIfs with multiple valid criteria in different columns

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

I'm trying to get excel to give me the average of multiple objects if they meet a criteria.
I want to calculate the average of the last column (SLA in days) for the lines that contain Country=ES/PL, Type of Email=all the G (G - PO question, G - Other...), in October

| Country | Type of Email | When received | SLA in days |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| BE | G - PO question | 02-10-23 | 1 |
| NL | G - Other | 02-10-23 | 1 |
| BE | G - Other | 03-10-23 | 1 |
| BE | AP - Non invoice | 03-9-23 | 1 |
| ES/PT | G - Log in | 10-10-23 | 1.00 |
| BE | AP - Non invoice | 10-10-23 | 2 |
| ES/PT | G - Other | 10-10-23 | 2.00 |
| ES/PT | G - Other | 11-10-23 | 1.00 |
| ES/PT | G - Forgot password | 11-10-23 | 1.00 |
| ES/PT | G - Forgot password | 12-10-23 | 1.00 |
| ES/PT | AP -Incomplete | 12-10-23 | 1.00 |
| ES/PT | AP -Incomplete | 13-10-23 | 1.00 |
| ES/PT | G - Forgot password | 13-10-23 | 1.00 |
| NL | G - Other | 13-9-23 | 2 |
| BE | AP - R17-Multiple | 13-9-23 | 2 |
| BE | AP - R17-Multiple | 13-9-23 | 2 |
| BE | AP -Incomplete | 16-Oct | 1 |
| ES/PT | G - Log in | 17-10-23 | 1.00 |
| BE | AP - R04-Incorrect | 13-9-23 | 2 |

How would you do it?
I use this formula but was wondering if there is another where I can add all the Types instead of just one "G*"

```
=AVERAGEIFS(D:D,B:B,"G*",A:A,"ES/PT",C:C,"<"&DATE(2023,10,31),Sheet1!C:C,">="&DATE(2023,10,1))
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at the illustration below:
[image: AVEREAGEIFS]
If you want to include **all** the types you simply omit this condition, if you want to include **selected** types you can use array constant as shown above.
It is important not to use simply `AVERAGE` function but divide `SUM` by `SUM(COUNT)` instead.
To include all October dates you should use either `"<="&DATE(2023,10,31)` or `"<"&DATE(2023,11,1)`